# app.setContext() in dialogflow v2 api?

Tags: actions-on-google

What is the equivalent of dialogflow's app.setContext() from v1 in the v2 API? Given the setup that the migration guide outlines (below), what call would you make to--for example--set a context when the welcome intent is triggered in the demo code below?

```
// v2
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');

const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('How are you?');
});

exports.factsAboutGoogle = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the context like this:

```
    const parameters = { // Custom parameters to pass with context
      welcome: true,
    };

    conv.contexts.set('welcome-context', 5, parameters);
```

The second parametr is for context lifespan.

In your example code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');

const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('How are you?');
  const parameters = { // Custom parameters to pass with context
      welcome: true,
    };
  conv.contexts.set('welcome-context', 5, parameters);
});

exports.factsAboutGoogle = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Then you can access the contexts with:

```
const contexts = conv.contexts;
```

Comment: The logic is not to do get to retrieve it? conv.contexts.get(parameters.welcome)