# How to change intents order dynamically in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have created several Intents in DialogFlow.
I am controlling the conversational flow of DiglogFlow using context.
I want to change the conversational flow dynamically using Firebase and Intents already created.

I think fullfillment can be a solution to this.

For example:
Let's say there are 2 Intents now: Booking a flight and Trip Course.
After Booking a flight, Trip course is executing now.
I want to add a Trip plan between Booking a flight and Trip course.

How can i use fullfillment at this time?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you update your question to give an example of what you expect the conversation to look like and how you think the flow should be changing? Do you have any code that is attempting to do this now? How are you doing this now with the Intents and Contexts - can you show screen shots? When you say "using firebase", do you mean using fulfillment code?

Comment: I have changed the question. I don't have any code.
I don't want a nested intents and manually changing input and output context in each Intents.

Comment: Can we use conv.followup for this purpose ? Can you please clarify it's usecase ?@Prisoner

Comment: I guess you should try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109823/app-setcontext-in-dialogflow-v2-api) and see it works for you.

Comment: @sai.raj - I am of the opinion that conv.followup() has little, if any, purpose. {: I still don't understand the question. Perhaps an example conversation would help illustrate what you're trying to do.